# Android - Resource not found crash on orientation change

Tags: java, android, layout

I have an app that works totally OK, the whole application is on SensorLandscape and the orientation wouldn't change at all,
but when I press the home key the orientation changes to portrait and the app throws Resource not Found Exception on this code :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_contact, parent, false);

    return rowView;
}
```

it can't find chat_contact layout.

android Manifest :

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest and the lifecycle methods of your activity?

Comment: @HusseinElFeky I've postet my AndroidManifest , i think my lifecycle methods is not the problem

Comment: The question is what directory is `R.layout.chat_contact`'s XML file in.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It's in layout-land

Comment: You should clearly have one for layout (default)

Answer (score 0):

It's because when your device is in portrait Mode and you try to open the application it by default try to load resources of portrait mode then later it will change the orientation to Landscape(based on your manifest configuration) So you can just add a default layout of launcher screen on portrait mode this will solve your resource not Found exception and application still be loaded in Landscape mode.

Comment: my app doesn't crash when launching.
It crashes when i exit the app by pressing home key ( pausing app )